# Problem caused by FP16 group quantization on vit-tiny

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, floating-point

I want to simulate the behavior of floating-point calculations on hardware, which is to align the floating-point exponent of a set of floating-point data, and then truncate the excess mantissa bits. I use this method to fine-tune the ViT-tiny model on ImageNet.
However once I quantify weights when training, it becomes non-convergent.

The training loss becomes weird, it increases after epoch 2 and can not decrease any more. I have tried original fp16 train, it can convergence well. What may happen after epoch2?
This is part of my training codes.

```py
    for step, data in enumerate(data_loader):
        images, labels = data
        sample_num += images.shape[0]
        images=images.to(device)
        if half_p:
            images=images.half()
        model.module.head.weight.data.copy_(tensor_aligned(model.module.head.weight.data,align=False,device=device,pad_val=-100))
        pred = model(images)
        pred_classes = torch.max(pred, dim=1)[1]
        accu_num += torch.eq(pred_classes, labels.to(device)).sum()

        loss = loss_function(pred, labels.to(device))
        loss.backward()
        accu_loss += loss.detach()

        data_loader.desc = "[train epoch {}] loss: {:.3f}, acc: {:.3f}".format(epoch,
                                                                               accu_loss.item() / (step + 1),
                                                                               accu_num.item() / sample_num)

        if not torch.isfinite(loss):
            print('WARNING: non-finite loss, ending training ', loss)
            sys.exit(1)
        model.module.head.weight.grad.copy_(tensor_aligned(model.module.head.weight.grad,device=device,pad_val=-100))
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
```

```py
def tensor_aligned(src,device,align=True,g_size=128,cut_num=0,pad_val=0):
        if align == True:
            src_shape=src.shape
            pad_size= int((g_size-src_shape[-1] % g_size) % g_size)
            _, exponent = torch.frexp(src)
            exponent=exponent.to(torch.int16)
            exponent=torch.nn.functional.pad(exponent,(0,pad_size),value=pad_val)
            pad_shape=exponent.shape
            exponent=exponent.reshape(-1,g_size)
            src=torch.nn.functional.pad(src,(0,pad_size)).reshape(-1,g_size)
            src=src.view(torch.int16)
            exp_max=torch.max(exponent,1).values.reshape(-1,1)
            exp_sft=exp_max-exponent
            exp_sft=torch.where(exp_sft>10,0,exp_sft)
            mask=torch.full(exp_sft.shape, -1, dtype=torch.int16).to(device)
            mask=torch.bitwise_left_shift(mask,exp_sft)
            src=torch.bitwise_and(src,mask)
            src=src.view(torch.float16)
            src=src.reshape(pad_shape)
            src=src[... , :src_shape[-1]]
        return src

I don't think it should have such a dramatic change, but I can't be sure whether this change is normal or if there is something wrong with my code.
```